# how to display data from controller to jsp using spring mvc?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I am unable to display data from controller to jsp page in spring, am new to spring, this is my controller

```
List<DocDto>  list =DocService.getDocs();
            DocDto docList = new DocDto();
            docList.setdocType(doc_type);
            docList.setdocSubType(doc_subtype);
            jobList.setTransactionId(transaction_id);   
            model.addAttribute("docList", docList);
```

This is my jsp table

```
 <c:forEach var="o" items="${list}">
 <tr> 
<td>
<c:out value="${o.doc_type}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${o.doc_subtype}" /></td>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is not displaying any data in my jsp, just simply blank table it is displaying. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ${list} use ${docList} in for each loop.
If it did not works then follow following steps :

Check you included proper jstl library in jsp

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

and using proper jar for jstl library.

Check DocDto for doc_type,doc_subtype variables properly spelled or not.

Comment: I tried with docList, then I have this error  javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt; yes the jstl lib is included in jsp, don't know what's the issue

Comment: I think you did not provide proper jstl jar.If it causing due to that then try to run one simple example for testing your libraries, ex: <http://roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/JSTLForLoop.shtml>

Comment: You tried that example which I provided you in link ? Try that if it runs correctly then only problem in taglib else in jar.If you are using maven <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
then use this dependency.

Comment: Now it works :) I gave the attribute name incorrect, it is working now. Thanks alot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your model attribute `docList`, but you're trying to reference it as `list`. Try

```
<c:forEach var="o" items="${docList}">
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have bind  model.addAttribute("docList", docList);   and you are trying to iterate by list you can use this  model.addAttribute("list ", docList); then iterate .Hope it will work