# How to list data from database in a web page in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have created a database called student base on the tutorial provided by tutorials point PDF, they have covered how to map the form and insert values in to the database using controllers, but they have not explained how to display the data from the database on to the webpage.

My code to list all students.

```
@Override
public List<Student> listStudents() {
    String SQL = "select * from Student";
    List<Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new StudentMapper());
    return students;
}
```

How to call this from my controller in spring and return the list to my webpage.

My contoller is given below

```
@Controller 
public class StudentController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
 public ModelAndView student() 
 { 
     return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student()); 
 } 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
 public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, ModelMap model) 
 { 
     ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
     StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");
     studentJDBCTemplate.create(student.getName(), student.getAge());
     model.addAttribute("name", student.getName()); 
     model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge()); 
     model.addAttribute("msg", "Student Enrolled"); 
     return "result"; 
 } 

 // How to write the listing controller?
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display data from controller to jsp using spring mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293017/how-to-display-data-from-controller-to-jsp-using-spring-mvc)

Comment: It did not explain how to create the function, like what the parameters should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the details you provide ,

```
public String ListStudents(ModelMap model) 
 { 
     List<Student> list= YourServiceClassObj.listStudents();
      model.addAttribute("result", list);
     return "View Name here"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AccountDAO {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public Account getAll(String user, String pass) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.USERR WHERE username=? AND password =?";
        try {
            conn = new DBContext().getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                return new Account(rs.getString(1),
                        rs.getString(2),
                        rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your controller and service methods should be like this .and then in the view use the controller returned attribute students.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String students(ModelMap model)
{
    List<Student> students= studentService.getStudents();
    model.addAttribute("students", students);
    return "student/studentList.html";
}
```

**Service :**

```
public interface StudentService {
    List<Student> getStudents();
}

@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
@Override
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}
```